Tropicalizing products of polynomials
I am currently reading the book "Essentials of Tropical Combinatorics" by Michael Joswig, and i have trouble to understand the proof of a Proposition therein. To state the proposition let me quickly fix some setup:
Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and let $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{F}\{\{t\}\}$ denote the field of Puiseux series with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$.
Furthermore we define $\text{ord}:\mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\}$ to be the valuation that takes $0$ to $\infty$ and any other element to the lowest exponent that appears in its series expansion.
$\textbf{Proposition 2.8.}$ Any two multivariate Laurent polynomials $f, g \in \mathbb{K}[x_1^{\pm 1}, \ldots, x_d^{\pm 1}]$ satisfy
\begin{align*}
%
\text{trop}(f \cdot g)(w) &= \text{trop}(f)(w) \odot \text{trop}(g)(w) \quad \text{and} \\
\text{trop}(f + g)(w) &\geq \text{trop}(f) \oplus \text{trop}(g)(w)
%
\end{align*}
for all $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Moreover if  $f$ and $g$ have sufficiently generic coefficients, the latter inequality becomes an equality, too.
I am concerened with the first claim only. The proof given in the book is as follows:
$\textbf{Proof.}$ Let $f = \sum_{u \in S}\gamma_u x^u$ and $g = \sum_{v \in T}\delta_v x^v$.
For $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ we compute
\begin{align*}
%
\text{trop}(f \cdot g)(w) &= \text{trop}(\sum_{u \in S, v \in T} \gamma_u \delta_v x^{u+v})(w) \\
&\overset{(*)}{=} \min\{ \text{ord}(\gamma_u) + \text{ord}(\delta_v) + \langle u+v, w \rangle \mid u \in S, v \in T\} \\
&= \min\{ \text{ord}(\gamma_u) + \langle u, w \rangle \mid u \in S\} + \min\{ \text{ord}(\delta_v) + \langle v, w \rangle \mid v \in T\} \\
&= \text{trop}(f)(w) \odot \text{trop}(g)(w) .
%
\end{align*}
I do not see why the equality $(*)$ should hold. Indeed we have
\begin{align*}
%
\text{trop}(\sum_{u \in S, v \in T} \gamma_u \delta_v x^{u+v}) 
= \bigoplus_{h} \text{ord}( \sum_{u+v = h} \gamma_u \delta_v) \odot X^{\odot h}
%
\end{align*}
and in general we can only say
$$ \text{ord}( \sum_{u+v = h} \gamma_u \delta_v) \geq \min_{u+v = h} \text{ord}(\gamma_u \delta_v)) .$$
For example $\sum_{u+v = h} \gamma_u \delta_v$ could be zero.
Any help on understanding this proposition is appreciated.

The answer to my question actually turns out to be quite easy.
Let $W_f = \text{trop}(f)(w)$ and similarly define $W_g$ and $W_{fg}$. We already know $W_{fg} \geq W_f + W_g$.
For the other inequality fix any monomial ordering $\geq$ and choose $ u_0 \in S$ to be minimal under all $u \in S$ satisfying $ \text{ord}(\gamma_u) + \langle u,w \rangle = W_f$. Choose $v_0 \in T$ in similar fashion.
Now for any $u \neq u_0, v \neq v_0$ with $u+v = u_0 + v_0$ we have $u < u_0$ or $v < v_0$.
Let us assume the former, then by choice of $u_0$ we have
$$\text{ord}(\gamma_u) + \langle u,w \rangle > W_f ~~~\text{and}~~~ \text{ord}(\delta_v) + \langle v,w \rangle \geq W_g .$$
Thus $$ \text{ord}(\gamma_u \delta_v) + \langle u+v,w \rangle > W_f + W_g = \text{ord}(\gamma_{u_0} \delta_{v_0}) + \langle u_0+v_0,w \rangle .$$
Since $u+v = u_0 + v_0$, we obtain $ \text{ord}(\gamma_u \delta_v) > \text{ord}(\gamma_{u_0} \delta_{v_0})$.
This gives $$ W_{fg} \leq \text{ord}(\sum_{u+v = u_0+v_0} \gamma_u \delta_v) + \langle u_0+v_0,w\rangle = \text{ord}( \gamma_{u_0} \delta_{v_0}) + \langle u_0+v_0,w\rangle = W_f + W_g .$$
Note that we have not used any special properties of the field $\mathbb{K}$ or the valuation $\text{ord}$. Hence the argument works over any (real) valued field.
